# Is there terminology for products/series and unions/intersections, similar to "quantifier" in logic?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a term that encompasses both (infinite) products and sums. "Series" seems to be exclusive to sums. Also, is there terminology for (inifinite) unions and intersections?

Comment: You mean you want a single word that encompasses both infinite sums and infinite products?

Comment: Perhaps you could give examples of how you would want to use these terms? As it stands, your question is too vague.

Comment: Yes. As well as a term for finite sums/products.

Comment: How is it too vague? A quantifier in logic is essentially a sum or a product. I'm thinking of a "map" in the computer science sense.

Comment: I was going to edit my comment but I couldn't do so because of some silly spam rule. What I mean is that the logical quantifiers are essentially sums (unions of statements) and products (intersections of statements). I like the word "quantifier". I wish there was a similar term for (infinite) sums/products, unions/intersections and disjunctions/conjunctions. It would be nice.